# Dynamic content is not working with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have view where I am adding dynamic content. I have added link on them (dynamic link). When click on it, not displaying alert.

I tried:

```
 $("a.reset_ebook").on("click", function() { alert("test") })
```

And view is:

```
<a ebook_id="18" class="reset_ebook" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a>
```

How to alert with dynamic added link?

Comment: Seems to be wroking fine [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/7yUdS/)

Comment: @DhavalMarthak That's not dynamic content though, so not relevant.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 $(document).on("click", "a.reset_ebook", function() { alert("test") })
```

This will listen for click events in the entire document but only trigger the handler if the target matches the selector (`a.reset_book`). That way it will also "work" for dynamically inserted elements.

Read more about direct and delegated events in the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax will not work for delegated events

```
 $(document).on("click", "a.reset_ebook", function() { alert("test") })
```

[**SEE HERE**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: You mean delegated *events*, right?

Comment: @David Thanks i updated